# Using Filepicker.io, uploading files into a folder in an S3 Bucket

Tags: filepicker.io

Can I upload files into a specific folder in an S3 bucket rather than just uploading into the base folder of the bucket?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the "path" parameter on the filepicker.store call.

```
filepicker.store(fpfile, {location:'S3', path:'myfolder/file.png'},
    function(stored_fpfile){
  console.log(stored_fpfile);
});
```

Documentation at https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#store